# NodeJS Sequelize query for find the nearest pins on map without dupe names

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have been stuck on this problem for over 1 day, here is the issue:

I have a database table called "pins", where I have columns "id", "name", "latitude" and "longitude"

There are data saved in this table for different pins, e.g.:

```
ID   Name   Latitude   Longitude
1    AAA    10          20
2    AAA    11          21
3    BBB    12          22
4    BBB    13          23
5    BBB    14          24
6    CC     15          25
```

OK, now I want to give a position on the map, say:
Latitude 13, Longitude: 22

I want to find the top 3 pins near this given location, ordered by the distance to this given location, without any dupe names.
Therefore, I want to have the result looks like this:

```
ID   Name   Latitude   Longitude
4    BBB    13          23
2    AAA    11          21
6    CC     15          25
```

How can I do that? Thank you very much!

I am using the following formula to calculate the distance:

```
6371 * 1000 * Acos(Cos(Radians("13")) * 
Cos(Radians(pins.latitude)) * Cos( 
Radians("22") - Radians(pins.longitude)) + Sin( 
Radians("13")) * Sin(Radians(pins.latitude)))
```

P.S.: I am using MySQL database 5.7

Answer (score 0):

There are my thoughts about how I will do it:

1. Find the top 3 unique pin titles within the distance
2. For every title discovered in step 1, find the closest pin
3. Return the pins collected in step 2 back to the client as a collection

However, I see this is a complicated solution, as step 2 requires iterating through the titles discovered in step 1, which results in multiple calls to the database for the query, not only introduce performance issues, also expensive as the API calls.

At the following is the code:

```
let result = [];
let query = {
    offset: 0, 
    limit: 3,
    attributes: [
        [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('name')) ,'name'],
    ],
    where: {
            Sequelize.where(calculateDistanceMethod(), '<=', 1000);  //Find the pins within 1KM
    }
};
let names = await connection.findAll(query);
for (let i = 0; names && i < names; i++) {
    let name = names[i];
    query = {
        offset: 0, 
        limit: 1,
        attributes: {
            include: [
                [calculateDistanceMethod(), 'distance']
            ]   
        },
        where: {
            name: name,
            Sequelize.where(calculateDistanceMethod(), '<=', 1000);  //Find the pins within 1KM
        },
        order: [
            [Sequelize.literal('distance'), 'ASC'],
        ]
    };
    let pList = await connection.findAll(query);
    if (pList) {
        result = result.concat(pList);
    }
}
return result;
```